# Correct XML structure for extending Magento Checkout classes

Tags: extensions, configuration, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm struggling to figure out the correct XML structure for extending magento classes which are deeper in the folder hierarchy than say `Core/Store.php`

For instance, how can I extend the following:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart/Api.php
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
```

I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <company_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </company_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <checkout_api>
                <rewrite>
                    <resources_customer>company_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer</resources_customer>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout_api>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

But haven't really gotten anywhere. Any ideas what the XML structure should be? And what would be a good resource to check out in order to better understand the extension logic in magento? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**EDIT**

I got the Customer.php rewrite working with the following config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart_api>Company_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api</cart_api>
                    <api_resource_customer>Company_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer</api_resource_customer>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

However, the Api.php rewrite does not seem to work. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but can't see it. Below is thew new Api.php. The folder structure for it is `app/code/local/Company/Checkout/Model/Cart/Api.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource {
    /**
     * Create new quote for shopping cart
     *
     * @param int|string $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function create($store = null)
    {
        $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);

        Mage::log("**REWRITE**");

        try {
            /*@var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote*/
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
            $quote->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setIsActive(false)
                    ->setIsMultiShipping(false)
                    ->save();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('create_quote_fault', $e->getMessage());
        }
        return (int) $quote->getId();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Using magento-ce 1.9.0.1

Comment: "company" is it uppercase or lowercase "c"?

Comment: In real world scenario it is an uppercase letter. I just replaced the company name with a general placeholder. Does the case really matter?

Comment: Should alway be uppercase see http://inchoo.net/magento/basic-folder-structure-for-new-magento-module/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rewrite something that is not a resource model you simply translate the class name into xml nodes like this:

```
 |- skip this
 |
Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api
          |     |      |
    |-----|-----|      |
<models>  |            |
   <checkout>      |---|
       <rewrite>   |
           <cart_api>Your_Class_Name_Here</cart_api>
       </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</models>
```

So if you are rewriting a model the top tag is `<models>`.  For blocks is `<blocks>` and so on.

Then you add the module name as a tag `<checkout>` in this case.
Then `<rewrite>` tag. This is fixed.
Then the rest of the class name with underscores and in lowercase.  `cart_api` in this case.

For resource models is a bit different.

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product` translates to

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource>
       <rewrite>
            <product>Your_Class_Name_Here</product>
       </rewrite>
    </checkout_resource>
</models>
```

The difference is that the tag below the `models` is not the module name `<catalog>`. It is `<{module}_resource>` and the tag inside `<rewrite>` your put the rest of the class name after `Model_Resource` in lowercase. `product` in my example.

But keep in mind that not all the class names that have `Resource` in them are resource models.  Only those that have `Resource` imediately after `Model`.
In your example `Mage_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer` is not a resource model so you can extend it by following the first example.

```
<models>
   <checkout>
       <rewrite>
           <api_resource_customer>Your_Class_Name_Here</api_resource_customer>
       </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</models>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I did get the Customer.php rewrite working with the following: `<api_resource_customer>Company_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer</api_resource_customer>` However the Api.php rewrite does not come in to effect with this `<cart_api>Company_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api</cart_api>`. Both are inside the same rewrite tag, is this legal?

Comment: Strange. It should work like that. And yes...you can put both rewrites inside the same `<rewrite>` tag.

Comment: Added some updates to my original question, in the hopes it might help pinpoint the problem with the Api.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <global>
        <models>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
        <cart_api>company_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api</cart_api>
                    <api_resource_customer>company_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer</api_resource_customer>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout_api>
        </models>
    </global>
```

StuctureL:

```
<global>
        <models>
            <modelprefix> <!-- model prefix model of checkout is Mage_Checkout -->
                <rewrite>
            <!-- Cart/Api.php rest class of cart_api  -->
            <cart_api>company_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api</cart_api>
                    <api_resource_customer>company_Checkout_Model_Api_Resource_Customer</api_resource_customer>
                </rewrite>
            </modelprefix>
        </models>
    </global>
```